# count() not working properly, returns 1

Tags: php, count, json

I got this part in an object:

```
[tcd_old_value] => {"14":{"name":"Nakon radnog vremena","name_changed":false,"added_cc":[],"removed_cc":["4"]},"15":{"name":"Dodatno radno vrijeme","name_changed":false,"added_cc":[],"removed_cc":["4"]}}
```

after `json_decode`

```
$json_object = json_decode(tcd_old_value);
```

I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Nakon radnog vremena
            [name_changed] => 
            [added_cc] => Array
                (
                )

            [removed_cc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                )

        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Dodatno radno vrijeme
            [name_changed] => 
            [added_cc] => Array
                (
                )

            [removed_cc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to count how many indexes are in this object (obviously the result should be 2)

```
$result = count($json_object);
echo $result //returns 1
```

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Oleg, thanks for the correction i grammar but unfortunately.. you are wrong.. 

its what am i doing wrong not I'm . and I'm is short for I am so please refrain from further editing of the grammar part in questions, as you have made errors here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `count()` in this case, because you have an object and not an array.

You may use the second parameter of `json_decode()` to have the JSON converted to an associative array:

```
$json_object = json_decode(tcd_old_value, true);
$result = count($json_object);
echo $result; // Now prints 2
```

Keep in mind that `$json_object` is no longer an object, but an array instead.

Comment: thx mate, it counts good but it complicted the rest of the code getting the data from the array... as i have already written the code to get the data from the object..

i have ussed count((array)json_object) as it is simple stdClass object..

but thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

As per the document `count`

> Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter
>   is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface,
>   1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is
>   NULL, 0 will be returned.

You may need to use

```
json_decode('json', true);
```

to convert as an array